# Move emails from from Deleted Items back to their orginal folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Someone I know went into the Large Emails "folder" and cleared it out thinking that those were just duplicates. She didn't realize that she was actually deleting the emails from her many folders.

Now, all the emails are in her Deleted Items folder. Since they came from several different folders, reorganizing them back to those folders is going to be a major task.

Is there any way in Outlook 2010 to select all the emails at once and tell it to move them back to the folders they were orginally in? This in a stand-alone environement (no Exchange Server).

Comment: Your subject was ignored. You will have to edit your question to emphasize that you do not need to recover items. I would put it on the first line. When you do that there will be no more answers.

Answer (score 5):

Click on Folder tab, and under the Clean Up section, click on Recover Deleted Items. There is also a select all option.

Answer (score 4):

The "Recover Deleted Items" item does *not* restore messages to their original location. Selecting the "Recover Deleted Items" button while in an Exchange account folder will let you recover messages *to* that folder, but they are not necessarily messages that were in that folder previously. It just presents you a listing of all deleted items with no indication of where they were deleted *from*.

As far as I know there is no way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom Rule in Outlook which moved all items sent to the mailbox recipient to the inbox and ran in in the Deleted Items folder.

Comment: This also just moves all the deleted items to the inbox - not what the question's asking to do

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

A user had 3000+ unread emails in their deleted items folder. I logged on to his machine and used control A to select all items and move all the items back to the inbox.

Took me a couple of minutes!

Comment: Your case is different. The asker has emails from various folders not just returning them back to the inbox.